# Geometric quantization of the moduli space of abelian Chern-Simons theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, research-level, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

I wish to understand [the statement in this paper more precisely](http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.0654):

> (1). Any 3d Topological quantum ﬁeld theories (TQFT) associates an inner-product vector space $H_{\Sigma}$ to a Riemann surface $\Sigma$.

- 

> (2) In the case of abelian Chern-Simons theory $H_{\Sigma}$ is obtained by geometric quantization of the moduli space of ﬂat $T_{\Lambda}$-connections on ${\Sigma}$. The
> latter space is a torus with a symplectic form

$$ ω =\frac{1}{4π} \int_{\Sigma} K_{IJ} \delta A_I \wedge d \delta A_J.$$

> (3) Its quantization is the space of holomorphic sections of a line bundle $L$ whose curvature is $\omega$. For a genus g Riemann surface $\Sigma_g$, it has dimension $|\det(K)|^g$.

- 

> (4) The
> mapping class group of $\Sigma$ (i.e. the quotient of the group of diffeomorphisms of $\Sigma$ by its identity component) acts projectively on $H_{\Sigma}$.  The action of the mapping class group of $\Sigma_g$ on $H_\Sigma$ factors through the group $Sp(2g, \mathbb{Z})$.

We are talking about this abelian Chern-Simons theory:
$$S_{CS}=\frac{1}{4π} \int_{\Sigma} K_{IJ}  A_I \wedge d  A_J.$$

> Can some experts walk through this (1) (2) (3) (4) step-by-step for focusing on this abelian Chern-Simons theory?

partial answer of (1)~(4) is fine.

I can understand the statements, but I cannot feel comfortable to **derive them myself**.

Comment: You may have interests to read this related paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.4863; which is from a more physical perspective, at least related to low energy physics of topological orders.

Answer (score 3):

See

[1] M. Bos and V.P. Nair. Coherent State Quantization of Chern-Simons Theory. International Journal of Modern Physics A, A5:959, 1990.

and chapter 20 of

[2] V.P. Nair. Quantum Field Theory: A modern perspective. Springer, 2005.

These references have geometric quantization of abelian Chern-Simons theory for $\Sigma=S^1 \times S^1$

(the first ref. has the non-abelian calculation too)